# How do I stop animation after it reaches end of div?

Tags: jquery, css, magento

I'm building a featured product slider for a Magento website and I have used the .animate method in jQuery to allow the div to slide the hidden content. I am new to Javascript/jQuery and I can't seem to find any answers to help me (and I don't really know the correct terminology either)

I need the .animate to stop after it has reached the end of the hidden div (which is 200%) Please see the code i have below.

```
$( function() {
      $('button.next-button').click( function() {
        $("#featured-slide").animate({right: '+=20%'});
      } );
} );

    $( function() {
      $('button.back-button').click( function() {
        $("#featured-slide").animate({right: '-=20%'});
      } );
} );
```

There is too much HTML for me to post, but #featured-slide is 200% wide. Is there a way to have a max right position or something similar?

I'm new to both Stack Overflow and jQuery in general so any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an unrelated post that had a jsfiddle relating to this problem. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/qpHSw/

```
var cur = 1;
var max = $("#featured-slide").children("li").length;

$('button.next-button').click( function() {

if (cur+1 > max) return;
    cur++;

$("#featured-slide").animate({
        right: "+=200px"});
} );

$('button.back-button').click( function() {

if (cur-1 < 1 ) return;
    cur--;

$("#featured-slide").animate({
        right: "-=200px"});
});
```